# R and gR difference in Vim

Tags: vim

When I use `R` and `gR` in vim where there are tabs, I don't notice the difference. According to Practical Vim,

> Virtual Replace mode is triggered with gR and treats the tab character
>   as though it consisted of spaces. Suppose that we position the cursor
>   on a tab stop spanning eight columns of screen real estate. If we
>   switch to Virtual Replace mode, we could type up to seven characters,
>   each of which would be inserted in front of the tab character.

But I can type exactly the same in R as well.

What are the difference between `R` and `gR`?

Comment: You may not notice a difference if you have `'expandtab'` set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>gR</kbd> do work as documented.

Let's say you have a file with the following content

<kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>

and use the default tabstop (8 characters).

If you edit this file, put the cursor on the first column and enter <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd>, you end up with this content:

<kbd>x</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>

The <kbd>x</kbd> replaced the first <kbd>tab</kbd> while the <kbd>y</kbd> replaced the <kbd>a</kbd>.

On the other hand, if you enter <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd>, you end up with that one:

<kbd>x</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>

The reason being you inserted 2 characters so stayed withing the first eight columns tab.